# Possessive for three-word company name

Tags: possessives

How do you use the possessive (apostrophe) with a company's name that consists of 3 words? For example,

> Barnacle Caribbean Cruises' complaint

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

If it is confusing for you, it might be confusing for others too.  In this particular example you should use "a complaint by Barnacle Caribbean Cruises". Or "a complaint against Barnacle Caribbean Cruises".

In other cases you can use a similar prepositional phrase, with "for" or "belonging to", or use the name as a noun adjunct (adjectival noun)

> "a complaint by Barnacle Caribbean Cruises",
> "a complaint against Barnacle Caribbean Cruises",
> "a person who works for Barnacle Caribbean Cruises",
> "A ship belonging to Barnacle Caribbean Cruises",
> "the Barnacle Caribbean Cruises website"